# What is the structure of Point2f in openCV?

Tags: opencv

I am confused about what does `Point2f` returns. I have `vector<Point2f> corner;` So, what would be the coordinate of rows and columns? Will  it be following:

```
int row_coordinate = corner[i].x;
int col_coordinate = corner[i].y;
```

But I get a segmentation fault if I take the above-mentioned convention. And if I do it like

```
int row_coordinate = corner[i].y;
int col_coordinate = corner[i].x;
```

then I get the results but then it seems to be opposite to the OpenCV documentation. Kindly tell me which one is correct. Would be very nice if you provide some documentation link (which I have already tried to search a lot).

Comment: The two code examples you gave are the same. I think you might have made a typo

Comment: Also, look at the bottom example in the Point_ section here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point

Comment: i have checked it but unfortunately i am unable to understand it..i have checked that page several times but unable to extract the information i need out of it

Comment: I just want to know whether `row = corner[i].x` or `row = corner[i].y`

Comment: row == x;    col == y;

Comment: @berak: but if i am using it....i get segmentation fault and if i reverse it or use `image.at<float>(corner[i]);` then it is working

Comment: @berak: i have tried to print the rows and cols of my image..my image is 480*640...and the range of `corner[i].x` is going beyond 480

Comment: gaa, no ofc. you're right, and i'm wrong. sorry for the confusion ....

Comment: @berak: sorry i don't know if you were really wrong or you are just sarcastic(m sorry, really didn't understand)...sorry i have been stuck on this problem for so long and really confused

Comment: no, for real. it's so easy to confuse that, so you're not alone .. ..  so it's : row=y; col=x;

Comment: @berak: could you please send me some link where it is written? i searched a lot but couldn't find any where it is written clearly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46963/discussion-between-user2440724-and-berak)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I'm correct, I assume you're confused with the coordinate system of OpenCV.

Since I always use x as width and y as height, in my program, I use OpenCV like this:

```
// make an image with height 100 and width 200   
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(100, 200, CV_8UC1);

int width = img.cols;
int height = img.rows;

cv::Point2f pt(10, 20);

// How do I get a pixel at x = 10 and y = 20 ?
int px = img.at<uchar>(pt.y, pt.x); // yep, it's inverted
```

What does it mean? OpenCV corrdinate system is based on rows and then columns. If you want to get pixels at (x, y) access it using (y, x)

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes, now i understood that x==width/cols and y==height/rows...but can you provide the link of some official documentation where it is written for example have a look at this page: http://tspp.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/x-y-coordinate-system-on-opencv/

Comment: sorry, I don't know :)

Comment: @azer89 got no idea where you can find it in the official documentation, but I can explain you WHY it is designed that way (at least I guess). Points are normally used in coordinate systems, having x (horizontal) and y (vertical) axis' by convention. While Matrices don't have x and y coordinates but rows and columns, and by convention in mathematics matrices are indexed row-first. So OpenCV uses Matrices and Points just as anyone would assume, the only "problem" is that IMAGES are embedded in matrices and that way two worlds are mixed. So `.at` is formally a matrix access and no pixel access

Comment: @azer89 here it's in the official documentation:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values
"
Note the ordering of x and y. Since in OpenCV images are represented by the same structure as matrices, we use the same convention for both cases - the 0-based row index (or y-coordinate) goes first and the 0-based column index (or x-coordinate) follows it. Alternatively, you can use the following notation: `Scalar intensity = img.at<uchar>(Point(x, y));`
"

Comment: Wow! Short and condense. Thanks.